# Making a discord bot and the way I'm adding roles is causing crashes

Tags: discord, bots

trying to make a level system that adds roles at certain levels but the bot is crashing everytime saying that at msg.member.roles.add() giving me a can't read properties of null (reading roles)

```html
if (Date.now() - userStats.last_message > 60000) {
        userStats.xp += between(15, 25);
        userStats.last_message = Date.now();
        //setup what xp needs for levels and reseting/setting levels and xp and adding roles for 
             certain levels
        const xpToNextLevel = 5 * Math.pow(userStats.level, 2) + 50 * userStats.level + 100;
        if (userStats.xp >= xpToNextLevel) {
            userStats.level++;
            userStats.xp = userStats.xp - xpToNextLevel;
            msg.channel.send(msg.author.username + ' has increased their chubee faith level to ' + 
              userStats.level + ' <a:pepesimp:881812231208181790> \n');
            if (userStats.level >= 1 && userStats.reached_level_1 === 0) {
                userStats.reached_level_1 = 1;
                msg.member.roles.add(chubee_follower);
                msg.channel.send(msg.author.username + ' is now a chubee follower. Welcome 
                  <a:chubee_pat:881808870681481216>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check if member is defined in the message before trying to give the role. This is because there are some cases (like DMing the bot) where member is not defined in the message.
You can do this by changing

```
msg.member.roles.add(chubee_follower);
```

for

```
if(msg.member) msg.member.roles.add(chubee_follower);
```

Comment: and what if it isn't defined? I don't understand how it wouldn't be defined anyways. this is all in the brackets of 'client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {'

Comment: If it is not defined you can't add the role to it, so you don't do anything. If the member is not define, the message was probably not from a server, so you shouldn't increase the level.

Comment: I don't know if this is my problem then, It still adds the role to the person... it just crashes directly afterwards throwing this error.

Comment: What do you mean? It gives the role to the member and then crashes?

Comment: yes... I'm very confused and frustrating because it's working as intended, but then throwing this error

Comment: Can you send me the crash logs?

Comment: Also, if the role is given and then crashing, try the code in the answer, that should work

Comment: it actually worked! thank you!

Comment: No problem, please mark this as the answer so if anyone have the same problem they know this will work. Thanks